# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - can't install necessary libs

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, compiz

I want to build Compiz so first I have to install all dependencies listed here: [link](http://wiki.compiz.org/C++Compiling) I can't install libgnome-window-settings-dev (**sudo apt-get install libgnome-window-settings-dev**), apt doesn't find that package. So when I run cmake without that lib I get following info:

```
-- checking for modules 'gnome-window-settings-2.0;gnome-desktop-2.0'
-- package 'gnome-window-settings-2.0' not found
CMake Error at cmake/CompizBcop.cmake:5 (message):
xsltproc not found.
```

How to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (since `xsltproc` isn't installed), you need to

```
sudo apt-get install xsltproc
```

Second, the easiest way to get the dependencies would be

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-dev
```